# Action plan for "merging" partitions on Linux only box without data loss

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

My Ubuntu LTS box is partitioned as shown in this GParted screenshot. There are separate ext4 partitions for root, usr, home, and a couple of ntfs data partitions (for Windows/Mac VM disk images). `/`, `/usr`, and `/home` partitions are adjacent to each other in this order.

Now it turns out that the `/usr` partition would be better off being larger than it is - during a recent update I an error message that it was out of space (there's ~2gb free).

`root` has some unused space but not enough to simply move the files in `/usr`. But,`/home` does have enough space to move all the files in `/usr`.

So I want `/usr` to have more space. I see two ways -

1. basically merge `/` and `/usr`. Copy (`cp -a`) all the files in `/usr` to `/home`, then delete the `usr` partition and expand `/` to include the unused space. Then move the `/usr` files from `home` to `root`. Is it enough to simply move/copy the contents to another partition?
2. shrink `/` and add space to `/usr`. I am not sure if doing this is straightforward. Is it?

I am not sure which is the better option, and if my approaches make sense. I plan to do it using GParted off a live boot USB. Please advice, if you know how to go about this and which option above is better.

[This question here was very helpful](https://superuser.com/questions/687770/how-can-i-merge-partitions-in-linux-without-losing-data) but not quite enough.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use `cp` to do this; maybe old prejudice from broken historical versions of cp that corrupt permissions, but you don't need to create the files on /home anyway.  Instead, use `tar` (as root) and save the files together as a single tar file and unpack that onto the new merged partition.

Comment: I suggest something like `tar cf /home/tmpsave.tar --one-file-system / /usr `

Comment: Ok, so just to reiterate for safety - I tarball the entire `/usr`, put it somewhere safe, then delete the partition containing `/usr` and extend the partition containing `/` into the now unused/empty space, and finally unpack the tarball into the all new spacious `/`. Right? I understand your paranoia about `cp`, `tar` is indeed safer.

Comment: The 3 partitions on the disk total 32GB of free space, so you could unify all three to have that much free space. In addition, the swap space might be too large if you never run out of RAM space. For example, [this article](https://opensource.com/article/19/2/swap-space-poll) recommends for RAM of 8GB–64GB the amount of 4G to 0.5X RAM, and when using hibernation the amount of 1.5X RAM.

Comment: I might want to keep the `/home` separate in case I want to install another distro or this one (for some unforeseen reason) break. Then at least the actual data is safe and I can confidently just reinstall the OS.

Comment: ...and of course, deleting and recreating the partitions will require booting from a live disk...

Comment: Yes ofc. That's assumed, as already mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 partitions on the disk, `/` and `/usr` and `/home`, total 32GB of
free space, so unifying all three will result in one partition that has
that much of free space.

In addition, the swap space might be too large if you never run out of
RAM space.

For example,
[this article](https://opensource.com/article/19/2/swap-space-poll)
recommends for RAM of 8GB–64GB the amount of only 4G to 0.5X RAM,
and if using hibernation the amount of 1.5X RAM.

If your RAM is 16GB and you use hibernation, then 24GB swap is enough,
which will free additional 5GB. And if you don't use hibernation and
allocate, say, 8GB of swap, then you gain rather about 20GB.

All in all, it's possible to arrive at having about 53GB of free space.